# How do I open a .class file?

Tags: java, class

If I have a .class file, how do I open it/view the source code? I think I have to decompile it first, but how the heck do I do that?

Comment: use jd-gui software

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just drag the .class file into your ide and it should show you the contents of that file, or you can use this http://www.javadecompilers.com/ to decompile the .class file.:)

Comment: A `.class` file contains Java Bytecode. What IDE are you using that shows Java source code when you drag a .class file in? Or are you being ironic? Sorry then ;)

Comment: When I open a .class file in eclipse it shows the contents of the .class file

Comment: Haha yes, you are technically right!

Comment: lol I actually up untill this point you could do it any other way i guess that's the beauty of some IDEs